# Как сделать такой border?

Tags: html, css

Подскажите как реализовать такую рамку, чтобы оставался пробел под заголовком.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: о каком пробеле под заголовком идет речь?

Comment: я думаю идет вопрос о "Кейсы нашей компании"

Comment: наложите сверху блок с заголовком, который будет бэкграундом закрывать бордер нижнего блока.
если Вы конечно о "Кейсы нашей команды"

Comment: @klifort тоже так думаю

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 1):

Пример (+ данного решения: работает на любом фоне (градиент, изображение))

```css
body {
  background: #291923;
}

fieldset {
  border-color: #fff;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

legend {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend align="center">Заголовок</legend>

  <p>Text</p>
</fieldset>
```

Пример с градиентом

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(255,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(109,0,25,1) 100%);
}

fieldset {
  border-color: #fff;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

legend {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <legend align="center">Заголовок</legend>

  <p>Text</p>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: а не знаешь можно ли как-то в ie сделать корректное отображение, а то он как я понял к legend стили не применяет

Comment: @kost1k - этот баг, но если добавить  align="center" для legend будет работать везде

Answer (score 0):

Один из способов

```css
.boby {
  background: white;
  padding-top: 30px;
}

.cell {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: -40px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background: white;
  padding: 0 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="boby">
  <div class="cell">
    <h1>TЕКСТ</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

вышло так

```css
.home {
  border:2px solid red;
  position:relative;
}
.home h2{
 position:absolute;
 top:-35px;
 background:white;
 left:50%;
 margin-left:-60px;
 width:90px;
 text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="home">
  <h2>TEXT</h2>
  <p>text text text text text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем то, что тебе надо, наверное

https://jsfiddle.net/6fqLsj9s/

https://jsfiddle.net/6fqLsj9s/1/

HTML

```
<div class = 'cover-block'>
TEXT
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.cover-block:before,
.cover-block:after {
    content:                  '';

    z-index:                  2;

  display:           inline-block;
    position:                absolute;

    border-style:           solid;

    top:                          0px;  
}

.cover-block:before {
    left:                       0px;

    border-width:           50px 0px 50px 25px;
    border-color:           transparent transparent transparent black;
}

.cover-block:after {
    right:                      0px;

    border-width:           50px 25px 50px 0px;
    border-color:           transparent black transparent;
}
```

**P.S.**

Вот вариант с одним уголком-границей
https://jsfiddle.net/6fqLsj9s/2/

Я наложил :after на :before, при этом :after на 1 пиксель меньше чем :before, а имеет цвет заднего фона, что дает иллюзию уголка.

Как сделать 2 уголка пока не знаю.

```
body {
  background: white;  
}

.cover-block {
  position: relative;

  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;

  border: 1px solid orange;
  border-left: none;

  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;

  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: calibri;
 }

.cover-block:before,
.cover-block:after {
    content:                  '';

  display:           block;
    position:                absolute;

    border-style:           solid;

  left:               0px;
}

.cover-block:before {
    top:                          0px;  
    border-width:           50px 0px 50px 25px;
    border-color:           transparent transparent transparent orange;
}

.cover-block:after {
  top:                1px;
    border-width:           49px 0px 49px 24px;
    border-color:           transparent transparent transparent white;
}
```

**P.P.S.**

2 уголка легко делается, если использовать не 1 div, а 3

```
<div>
    <div class = 'left'></div>
    <div class = 'content'>TEXT</div>
    <div class = 'right'></div>
</div>
```

и к каждому уголку применить код (чуть модифицированный), который я привел для одноуголкового примера.

**P.P.P.S**

Уф - получилось, как описал выше: https://jsfiddle.net/6fqLsj9s/3/

Пришлось ввести дополнительные блоки (2 штучки)

HTML:

```
<div class = 'cover-block'>
    <div class = 'left'></div>TEXT<div class = 'right'></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  background: white;  
}

.cover-block {
  position: relative;

  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;

  border: 1px solid orange;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;

  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;

  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: calibri;
 }

 .left,
 .right {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;

   width: 0px;
   height: 100%;
 }

.left {
  left: 0px;
}

.right {
  right: 0px;
}

.left:before,
.left:after,
.right:before,
.right:after {
    content:                  '';

  display:           block;
    position:                absolute;

    border-style:           solid;
}

.left:before,
.left:after {
  left:               0px;
}

.left:before {
    top:                          0px;  
    border-width:           50px 0px 50px 25px;
    border-color:           transparent transparent transparent orange;
}

.left:after {
  top:                1px;
    border-width:           49px 0px 49px 24px;
    border-color:           transparent transparent transparent white;
}

.right:before,
.right:after {
  right:               0px;
}

.right:before {
    top:                          0px;  
    border-width:           50px 25px 50px 0px;
    border-color:           transparent orange transparent transparent;
}

.right:after {
  top:                1px;
    border-width:           49px 24px 49px 0px;
    border-color:           transparent white transparent transparent;
}
```

Comment: спасибо, тоже будет полезно, а я вот так извращался https://codepen.io/kost1k/pen/xPQKBa